# Lipschitz Implies a Bounded Derivative

Tags: analysis, lipschitz-functions

I want to prove that if $f$ is Lipschitz and is assumed to be continuous on some interval $[a,b]$ and differentiable on $(a,b)$, then $f'$ is bounded on $(a,b)$.

I know that because $|f(x)-f(y)|$ $\leq$ $M|x-y|$,

I can say that  $\left \vert \frac{f(x)-f(y)}{x-y}\right \vert\leq M$.

The next step is where I get lost. Why does it then follow that for all $x \in [a,b]$, $\left \vert\lim_{(x→y)} \frac{f(x)−f(y)}{(x-y)}\right\vert≤M$? Is that just a basic assumption that I can make?

Thanks!

Comment: If $a_n \leq M$ then $\lim a_n \leq M$.  Simple as that.

Answer (score 2):

By the Lipschitz condition, 
$$ \frac{|f(x) -f(y) |}{|x-y|} \leq M$$ for all $x,y \in [a,b]$. This implies that as long as the limit in question exists, it will be $\leq M$.

Answer (score 0):

Lipschitz functions are always continuous (by definition, you have their modulus of continuity).

Derivatives exists only Lebesgue almost everywhere. For details, you should take a look to Rademacher theorem (see for istance Evans Gariepy, Measure theory and fine properties of functions).
To get bounds of incremental ratios you could use $\limsup$ and $\liminf$ with trivial bounds given by your Lipschitz condition.